# Read File And Split Into Multiple Parts Based On Flag in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, text-files, delimiter, text-processing

I have a text file I would like to process and import.  The `< TEAM >` line contains a team with data related to it under it.  It then repeats the process when another line contains `< TEAM >`.  My question is instead of keeping track or the lines and grabbing the data, or processing them sequentially, is there a way to read the flag (`< TEAM >`), and store all data under it in a string before the next `< TEAM >` in C#?  Id like to process that list of strings one by one afterwards.  The code below works but I'd like to retain < TEAM >, in the string.

```
var teams = file.ReadToEnd().Split(new [] {  "< TEAM >" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

< TEAM >
NAME    ADDRESS CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP
Spokane Legacy 16U  1111 S Rowan Terrace Lane   Spokane Washington  US  99206
< COACHES >
DUTY    NAME    ADDRESS CITY    STATE   PROVINCE    COUNTRY ZIP PHONE   EMAIL   APPROVAL NUM    BBCS APPROVED

< TEAM >
NAME    ADDRESS CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP
Spokane Legacy 16U  1111 S Rowan Terrace Lane   Spokane Washington  US  99206
< COACHES >
DUTY    NAME    ADDRESS CITY    STATE   PROVINCE    COUNTRY ZIP PHONE   EMAIL   APPROVAL NUM    BBCS APPROVED
```

Comment: you could just add it back in to each item in teams.

Comment: I know, but I was wondering if there was something more elegant..haha

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack but should work

```
string[] splitTeams = teams.Replace("< TEAM >", "|< TEAM >").Split(new [] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

That should work as long as `|` isn't used anywhere else in your file. If it is, then just substitute it with a unique character or a string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like, Not very elegant, but it works if `< TEAM >` only needs the 2 lines under it (Header and Data)

```
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines("c:\\stackoverflow.txt");
    var result = lines.Select((s, i) => s.Equals("< TEAM >") ? lines.Skip(i).Take(3) : null).Where(x => x != null);
```

Returns:

```
< TEAM >
NAME    ADDRESS CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP
Spokane Legacy 16U  1111 S Rowan Terrace Lane   Spokane Washington  US  99206

< TEAM >
NAME    ADDRESS CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP
Spokane Legacy 16U  1111 S Rowan Terrace Lane   Spokane Washington  US  99206
```